Mac detect event keyboard is pressed but not the actual key data itself
I am building a Time Tracking app for Macos that takes screenshot of the screen every 1 minute but pauses when the user is inactive. To define being active, I check if the user moves mouses and or any keyboard key it tapped.
// Function to check for mouse movement
func monitorMouseActivity() {
    NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: [.mouseMoved]) { _ in
        resetActivityTimer()
    }
    NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: [.leftMouseDown, .rightMouseDown, .otherMouseDown]) { _ in
        resetActivityTimer()
    }
}

// Function to check for keyboard activity
func monitorKeyboardActivity() {
    NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown) { event in
        resetActivityTimer()
        return 
    }
    NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown) { event in
            resetActivityTimer() // Reset the activity timer on any key press
            return event // Pass the event along
        }
}

It works fine with mouse events.
However, I am not getting any keyboard event. I checked this Adding a global monitor with NSEventMaskKeyDown mask does not trigger and it says that I have to disable Sandbox.
However, I won't be able to deploy to App Store if this is disabled. It don't consider my app as a privacy risk as I don't care about the keyboard data, I just care about the fact that it is pressed or not. Is there an API to achieve this without disabling Sandbox ?

Have you tried [Best way to know if application is inactive in cocoa mac OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039788/best-way-to-know-if-application-is-inactive-in-cocoa-mac-osx/17656688#17656688}?

The problem is I want to test if the entire OS is inactive not just the application

Have you read this answer? It says "number of seconds the machine has been idle".
